# Detecting audio peaks

Tags: vb.net, audio

Is it possible to detect peaks in audio (from mp3 or wav files)? I have been creating a music player in the new Windows 8 .NET environment and so far my options seem very limited. I wish to use the information about the audio peaks to trigger an event. Can anyone shed some light on how I could accomplish this?

Comment: The [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/) library might have something to offer.